# Custom config files(xml) not transformed with Slowcheetah Extension when publishing for Azure Web Role

Tags: visual-studio, azure, slowcheetah, webrole

I'm searching if SlowCheetah is available for Azure Web Role.

・Visual Studio 2012
・Azure SDK 2.6

When I create package(.cspkg), I found that web.config is transformed by each build settings but other custom config files are not transformed.

I have two build settings, "pre" and "pro" .
(test.config, test.pre.config, test.pro.config)

I'm trying to make a package with the pre build setting, but the output file in cspkg remains unchanged.

My questions are the following..

1. Can I use SlowCheetah to transform custom xml files for Azure Web Role?
2. If the first answer is no, are there any alternative ways?

Comment: Hi Byan . Thank you for you help! I'm not good at english..